# Whether $display syntax works during post-route simulation in verilog HDL

Tags: verilog, verification, test-bench

I am trying to monitor one internal signal during post-route simulation.

So I used **`$display`** syntax within the verilog code.

However, in console nothing is showing.

I used the following syntax within my verilog code

```
always @(negedge clk)
begin
$display("Decimal: %d", idatabuf); 
end
```

So my question is whether the **`$display`** syntax does not work for post route simulation?

Anyways, I am going the crude way of getting the internal signal as output. But, if the syntax **`$display`** works, my life would be more easier.

Comment: If you're adding this `$display` to your RTL, then as the others have said, synthesis will remove it. You ought to be able to add it to your post-layout netlist, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Laleh said, `$display` is not synthetizable. To do what you want you should use hierarchical reference on your signal after synthesis in your testbench. e.g. In your testbench you can add:

```
always@* 
  $display("Decimal: %d", u_top.u_mymod.idatabuf);`
```

It should print `idatabuf` each time it changes.

N.B.: If the signal you want to monitor is an internal signal and not a pin of a hierarchical module, synthesis tools tend to simplify for logical optimization. If you want to monitor such a signal you should bind to drive a black box input. In Synopsys tools, the simplest way to make a black box is to create an empty module.

```
module BlackBox (I,O);
  parameter SIZE=1;
  input [SIZE-1:0] I;
  output[SIZE-1:0] O;
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

No. $display is not synthesizable so it only works in behavioral simulation.
All non-synthesizable parts of code such as & and # are ignored during synthesis process.